# IntelliJ Idea groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Conflicting module versions

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy, spring-boot

My maven builds are fine and able to run groovy from cli. However if I try to run my groovy class inside IntelliJ Idea (version 15 community edition), its gives me below error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.<clinit>(InvokerHelper.java:61)
at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.<init>(GroovyObjectSupport.java:32)
at groovy.lang.Closure.<init>(Closure.java:219)
at groovy.lang.Closure.<init>(Closure.java:236)
at groovy.lang.Closure$1.<init>(Closure.java:203)
at groovy.lang.Closure.<clinit>(Closure.java:203)
at filter.App.<clinit>(App.groovy)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:122)
Caused by: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Conflicting module versions. Module [groovy-all is loaded in version 2.3.9 and you are trying to load version 2.4.5
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl$DefaultModuleListener.onModule(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:509)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.m12n.ExtensionModuleScanner.scanExtensionModuleFromProperties(ExtensionModuleScanner.java:77)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.m12n.ExtensionModuleScanner.scanExtensionModuleFromMetaInf(ExtensionModuleScanner.java:71)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.m12n.ExtensionModuleScanner.scanClasspathModules(ExtensionModuleScanner.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.<init>(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:110)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.<init>(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:71)
    at groovy.lang.GroovySystem.<clinit>(GroovySystem.java:33)
    ... 10 more
```

Not sure how to get rid of this.

This is my pom dependency.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

And I am using spring boot.

```
 <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath></relativePath>
</parent>
```

This is my groovy version installed in system.

```
Groovy Version: 2.4.5 JVM: 1.8.0_60 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Linux
```

Please let me know if someone knows about this.

Comment: You're loading it in to intellij somewhere else

Answer (score 24):

you have to delete groovy lib from project settings.

shift+alt+ctrl + s, global libraries - delete groovy. And when trying to run applictaion / test you should have point to groovy from maven dependencies.

Comment: That fixed my problem in my Gradle build. Thanks.

Comment: @minsk just project settings

Answer (score 12):

@SuperAndrew's suggestion wasn't my situation -- I didn't have Groovy registered under Global Libraries under my Project Structure. But I did find [this StackExchange solution resolved my issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33262366/3855777). Add this code to your `build.gradle` file.

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.4'
    }
}
```

Comment: how will this be if I use kotlin (`build.gradle.kts`) file?

Comment: thanks for the solution; would be good to add this goes into the "buildscript" section for those not as familiar with gradle like me :)

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing this in a recent project after I upgraded Gradle to 7.+

The reason this was causing a problem for me was that Gradle 7.+ is now using Groovy 3.+ and as such various other plugins needed to be upgraded (e.g. spock-core).

It was this incompatibility of various dependencies that were causing this and once I updated all of them this issue went away.