# Gradle project shows version mismatch and the project is not building

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

I am using gradle to build my gradle project. After I run gradle build, it is showing me error:  java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
When I fetched the stacktrace of the error, I got this:

```
Caused by: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Conflicting module versions. Module [groovy-datetime is loaded in version 3.0.8 and you are trying to load version 2.5.8
```

I looked over internet and I can see several resolutions including adding the following to the dependencies:

```
compile gradleApi()
    compile localGroovy()
    testCompile("org.spockframework:spock-core:1.3-groovy-2.5") {
        exclude group:'org.codehaus.groovy'
    }
```

But it didn't resolve the issue. I have dependencies added to my gradle as:

```
testImplementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.5.10'
    testImplementation 'org.spockframework:spock-core:1.3-groovy-2.5'
    testImplementation 'org.spockframework:spock-spring:2.0-M3-groovy-3.0'
```

Please help me resolve the issue and what exactly needs to be changed to overcome this.

Comment: Any help would be appreciated as I am running late to complete the project.

Comment: maybe try deleting groovy lib from project settings.

Comment: Still getting the same error. I removed the groovy lib from external libs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IntelliJ Idea groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Conflicting module versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35520767/intellij-idea-groovy-lang-groovyruntimeexception-conflicting-module-versions)

Comment: Tried deleting the groovy lib from external libraries and there is no mention of the lib in the global libraries under project settings. So didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried all the mentioned solutions?

Comment: Yes, the first solution of the post is only useful in my case and it is not working. As part of the solution I tried deleting the groovy lib from external libraries and there is no mention of the lib in the global libraries under project settings. So this is what I did. In the project settings under libraries I deleted all libs with groovy mentioned in them. Do I need to do anything else?

Comment: Don't mix Spock 1.3 with 2.0. The latter includes Groovy 3.0, and you are using Groovy 2.5.